# JavaScript : Testing Promises with Timeout and conditions

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, mocha.js, es6-promise

I am trying to test my REST APIs using Mocha and Chai.

Below is code snippet

```js
"use strict"

// all required varibles modules declaration

describe("Get Data", function () {
  it("Get Final Data", function () {
    return getFinalResponse(
      "https://localhost/getdata",
      "GET",
      JSON.stringify(rawdata)
    )
      .then((response) => response)
      .then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response)
        let jsonData = await response.json()
        operationId = jsonData.operation
        console.log(jsonData.operation)
      })
  })
})

function delay(t) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, t))
}

async function restCall(url, method, data) {
  const signer = new common.DefaultRequestSigner(provider)

  const httpRequest = {
    uri: url,
    headers: new Headers(),
    method: method,
    body: data,
  }

  await signer.signHttpRequest(httpRequest)

  const response = await fetch(
    new Request(httpRequest.uri, {
      method: httpRequest.method,
      headers: httpRequest.headers,
      body: httpRequest.body,
    })
  )

  return response
}

async function getFinalResponse(url, method, data) {
  let response
  do {
    await delay(10000)
    response = await restCall(url + "/done", method, data)
  } while ((await response.json()["status"]) !== "DONE")

  return restCall(url, method)
}
```

The condition `while(await  response.json()["status"] !== 'DONE')` breaks/terminates in 1 minutes but even after putting 2 minutes as mocha time out . I am not getting the expected output.

Kindly help me what might be the issue.

Comment: where's your error handling? perhaps there's an error

Comment: Shouldn't the `it` callback get a function callback parameter named `done`? Thus you can call `done()`, once the test completes? Or is it already promise aware? Otoh, you always call `restCall` with the same parameters, why would it ever return the `status` `DONE`? What are you actually testing here?

Comment: @hgb123 You not only changed formatting, but you also edited parts of the OP's code (like the while condition), was that intentional?

Comment: No I didn't change any thing apart from url as it is confidential. I need to keep calling the endpoint till I get status as DONE

Comment: @Jaromanda X  error says timeout exceeded ,but if I run the endpoint independently it gives me DONE status i.e. Expected response within 1 minute.but while running as conditional promise with loop I don't get the same.

Comment: Rajeev, I was talking about the editor who changed something :) Did you already check what data you are actually checking? Did you debug by verifying that it is indeed `DONE` that is send back in status, and not `done` for example? As we don't have an idea what your endpoint returns, it's hard to give any suggestions. If you could post the output of the responses in the loop, that could be something already

Comment: ```await  response.json()["status"] !== 'DONE'``` should clearly be ```(await  response.json())["status"] !== 'DONE'```

Comment: Avoid mixing `await` and `.then()` syntaxes. It just causes cinfusion.